# Read and write files in development machine - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to write in my **local** (not simulator) filesystem from an ios app developed with xcode, when I am running the app with Xcode's simulator ?

Reason: I have an ios application and I would like to have some content that the user could fetch as JSON data from my server. However, I would also like this JSON data to be generated from my (development) version, locally (so that I am sure it is exactly in the right format). I would therefore like my application to read and write in something like `~/User/myself/my_website/my_data/` rather than in the simulator's folder. Obviously this code would only be active in the development version and not in the release version (it doesn't need to be app review compatible).

Comment: Ques still not clear. :/

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: Your requirement.

Comment: First of all use proper technical words, the simulator folder you are saying is called document directory. If you explain your question like this then how other person can understand. Still you have done lots of things like this. So re-structure your question otherwise it is unclear.

Comment: Sorry but I thought the principle of Stackoverflow was to ask questions about things you don't necessarily know perfectly, so not necessarily knowing what the best technical terms around the matter are, and to do your best to describe your problem in a clear way. This is what I did and if some specific is not clear you can let me know (for me the question makes sense and can be understood, so it's hard to tell what others won't understand). It's a pitty Stackoverflow suffers from such unfriendly behavior and comments like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out it was trivial, and much simpler than writing on the device. Just specify a path to write to in the form of an absolute path and do `[stringData writeToFile:path ...]`.